# awesome-share-buttons where is the application.coffee file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

I am installing the gem awesome-share-buttons to implement social media share buttons on my rails app. I noticed it calls for adding this line:

```
#= require awesome-share-buttons
```

to your application.coffee file, however, that doesn't exist. Would I make this file and add it there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I realized you can simply place it inside of your application.js file and change

```
#= require awesome-share-buttons
```

to

```
//= require awesome-share-buttons
```